# Use union to combine data between 2 TBLs

Tags: union

I have 2 Queries as below:

1. 1st Query

| Expr1 | SumOfBRK |
| --- | --- |
| 08/03/2021 | 32499 |
| 09/03/2021 | 2687 |
| 28/02/2021 | 355 |

```
SELECT Format([TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE],"Short Date") AS Expr1, Sum(TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfBRK FROM TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT GROUP BY Format([TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE],"Short Date");
```

2. 2nd Query

| Expr1 | SumOfSTD |
| --- | --- |
| 08/03/2021 | 6178 |
| 09/03/2021 | 4135 |
| 28/02/2021 | 2845 |

```
SELECT Format([TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE],"Short Date") AS Expr1, Sum(TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfSTD FROM TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT GROUP BY Format([TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE],"Short Date");
```

I expect the result as follows:

| Expr1 | SumOfSTD | SumOfBRK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08/03/2021 | 6178 | 32499 |
| 09/03/2021 | 4135 | 2687 |
| 28/02/2021 | 2845 | 355 |

Anyone can help me ? I tried to use the union to combine them but the result was not what I expected

Thank you.

Bosco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a *join* here, rather than a union:

```
SELECT t1.Expr1, t2.SumOfSTD, t1.SumOfBRK
FROM
(
    SELECT FORMAT([TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE], "Short Date") AS Expr1,
           SUM(TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfBRK
    FROM TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT
    GROUP BY FORMAT([TBL_BRK_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE], "Short Date")
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT FORMAT([TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE], "Short Date") AS Expr1,
           SUM(TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfSTD
    FROM TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT
    GROUP BY FORMAT[TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE], "Short Date")
) t2
    ON t2.Expr1 = t1.Expr1;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much, I am using access sql, so there is not "with" keyword , can you help convert that sql command to access sql ?

Comment: I tried to use that your sql command and it shows an error (Syntax error in From Clause), I am using Access 2016.

Comment: After checking again, I found out that the sql command is missing "(" in FORMAT[TBL_STD_DATA_OUTPUT].[DATE].
 I have added it and it works. Thank you so much Tim.